# CSV File-Pandas dataFrame column separation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this data set as such,
[image]

As you can see that 3rd column (Age at , start of presidency ) have been merged  as well as 4th column(Age at, end of presidency)
How can I separate them ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did these items have a delimiter in the original CSV file?  If so, they should have been separated when you created the Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible split by uppercase:

```
data = [{'Age atend of presidency': '65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797'}, 
        {'Age atend of presidency': '65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797'}
         ,{'Age atend of presidency': '65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df[['age1','end2']] = df['Age atend of presidency'].str.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", expand=True).iloc[:, :-1]
print (df)
            Age atend of presidency               age1         end2
0  65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797  65 years, 10 days  Mar 4, 1797
1  65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797  65 years, 10 days  Mar 4, 1797
2  65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797  65 years, 10 days  Mar 4, 1797
```

Or you can split by `days`:

```
df[['age1','end2']] = df['Age atend of presidency'].str.split("days", expand=True)
df['age1'] += 'days'
print (df)
        Age atend of presidency               age1         end2
0  65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797  65 years, 10 days  Mar 4, 1797
1  65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797  65 years, 10 days  Mar 4, 1797
2  65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797  65 years, 10 days  Mar 4, 1797
```

Or:

```
df[['age1','a', 'end2']] = df['Age atend of presidency'].str.split("(days)", expand=True)
df['age1'] += df.pop('a')
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is STR you can use X.split(','). For example:

```
 df['Age atend of presidency'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

if it is not a STR

```
df['Age atend of presidency'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(','))
```

or

```
df['Age'] = df['Age atend of presidency'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
df['days'] = df['Age atend of presidency'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
df['date'] = df['Age atend of presidency'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[2])
```